# java modularization and cxf-xjc-plugin generated packages from xsd files

Tags: java, cxf, java-module, cxf-xjc-plugin

I have a module

```
module-info.java
```

--

```
module my.module.with.cxf.generated.packages {
    requires slf4j.api;
    requires spring.context;
    requires java.persistence;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires org.apache.cxf.core;
    requires java.xml;
    requires java.xml.bind;
    opens cxf.generated.package.no.one to my.other.module
    opens cxf.generated.package.no.two to my.other.module 
    exports cxf.generated.package.no.one to my.other.module
    exports cxf.generated.package.no.two to my.other.module
}
```

--

and then `my.other.module`

```
module-info.java
```

--

```
module my.other.module {
     requires my.module.with.cxf.generated.packages
}
```

--

and I get that that

`package cxf.generated.package.no.one is not visible`

while compiling the code. What I'm doing wrong? How to fix this issue?

Additional information

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.1
Java 11
cxf-xjc-plugin 3.3.1
```

Comment: good to learn that the order matters, but does `opens` not suffice for your use case?

Comment: if i put opens (and skipping exports I get 'the package [package name] is not visible')

Comment: alright, whatever does good for you, though not really sure of your use case to both export and opens packages to other modules. :)

Answer (score 1):

So, after trial and error I discovered that arranging packages so that exports go prior
to opens yields a compiled result

```
module my.module.with.cxf.generated.packages {
    requires slf4j.api;
    requires spring.context;
    requires java.persistence;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires org.apache.cxf.core;
    requires java.xml;
    requires java.xml.bind;
    exports cxf.generated.package.no.one to my.other.module
    exports cxf.generated.package.no.two to my.other.module
    opens cxf.generated.package.no.one to my.other.module
    opens cxf.generated.package.no.two to my.other.module 
}
```